# How to enable this eclipse scroll bar?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, scrollbar, pydev, perspective

When editing Python code I get this scroll bar (even in Java perspective):

http://pasteboard.co/22Uf7QhU.png

I have installed the PyDev plugin which gave me this bar but is it not possible to use it for Java?

I would like to see this when editing in Java rather than the standard Window's style scroll bar
but I don't know how to enable it or even what it is called.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the PyDev 'Overview Ruler Minimap'.

It is solely a feature of the PyDev plugin and is not available for other languages.

Comment: Pity. Was looking for it to use with js and php